# Why IsNull it doesnt worK?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run this query and when it doesnt find value i need to take result 0.neither my return is null or empty.

```
 select top(1) 
 ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),a.VatValue),0) as VatC 
 from VatCodes a 
 join 
 InventoryMainGroupItems b on a.VatcodeID = b.VatCodeID 
 join InventoryTransTemp c on c.CategoryID = b.MainGroupItemID 
 where 
 c.TrnDocumentID = '409' 
 and 
 a.VatcodeID = 3
```

Now my column returns emtpy.
My desired result should be 0
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: but does it actually return a result?, are there any rows that match your `where` condition?

Comment: yes they are match. But i need to check from my rows only if VatValue exists and if exists to get it

Comment: Does the VatValue column allow nulls? Also, with `TOP(1)` your query will only return one row

Comment: can you post your actual result?

Comment: I think isnull() only works with null values not empty values

Comment: Yes i change it in null and i get same result.Updated

Comment: Show the definition of the VatCodes table

Comment: the `NULL` value you are showing isn't actually there, though. It's just a representation from the wizard for manually adding new rows to that table

Comment: But there are not exist rows that contain this VatValue in my main table.So why i dont get null?

Comment: That's why I initially asked if there was an actual result. If there are no rows that match your `WHERE` criteria, then you get **no rows as a result**, not a `NULL` value.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 possibilities.

1. No rows meet the conditions as specified in the joins and where clause. [Also, I'd start using explicit joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
2. The column `VatValue` doesnt' contain any `NULL` values, but instead contains empty spaces which isn't the same as `NULL`

Try to use replace to test for the empty string.

```
 select top(1) 
 ISNULL(REPLCACE(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),a.VatValue),'',0),0) as VatC 
 from VatCodes a 
 join 
 InventoryMainGroupItems b on a.VatcodeID = b.VatCodeID 
 join InventoryTransTemp c on c.CategoryID = b.MainGroupItemID 
 where 
 c.TrnDocumentID = '409' 
 and 
 a.VatcodeID = 3
```

If that doesn't work, your condition isn't returning any rows. Here's a way to prove that... this shouldn't return any rows....

```
 select top(1) 
 a.VatValue as VatC 
 from VatCodes a 
 join 
 InventoryMainGroupItems b on a.VatcodeID = b.VatCodeID 
 join InventoryTransTemp c on c.CategoryID = b.MainGroupItemID 
 where 
 c.TrnDocumentID = '409' 
 and 
 a.VatcodeID = 3
```

Comment: It doesnt work.Maybe i will try another way for acheive this

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think the `InventoryMainGroupItems` has rows with a null in the `VatCodeId` column.

If this is the case then you can amend your slightly like so

```
 select top(1) 
 ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),a.VatValue),0) as VatC 
 from InventoryMainGroupItems b
 LEFT join 
 VatCodes a  on a.VatcodeID = b.VatCodeID 
 INNER JOIN InventoryTransTemp c on c.CategoryID = b.MainGroupItemID 
 where 
 c.TrnDocumentID = '409' 
 and 
 a.VatcodeID = 3
```

Comment: Forget it. Thank you for help i wil try another way